# load namespaces into OPC UA server c#

Tags: c#, .net, server, namespaces, opc-ua

Inside an OPC UA server, the namespace is identified by a namespace index. Index 0 is always the base namespace (http://opcfoundation.org/UA/) and it's mandotary, and index 1 is for any instances of nodes which do not belong to a specific namespace.
Depending on usecase, a server can load additional namespaces. These namespaces normally start at index 2.
this is an Illustration, the value has the various loaded namespaces.[image]

**My question: how to load the namespaces into the server.** I'm using c# .net

Comment: Look like you want to add a Time Server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on the C# OPC UA SDK vendor. But typically there is a NodeSetManager which loads the behind code for the individual namespaces.